# dnsmasq for looking up `.local` domains on the clients that don't support mDNS

Tags: linux, dns, dnsmasq, mdns, avahi

`mDNS` (e.g. avahi, bonjour) allows a machine to advertise itself as `machine-name.local` on its LAN, and allows clients to look it up by that domain name instead of by IP.

Most platforms support `mDNS` out of the box, but infamously android doesn't.

i.e. if I want to connect to a service running in my local network through a browser on my android, instead of using `machine-name.local:port` I'd have to use `ip-address:port`. This can be frustrating when ip is dynamic and changing.

I'm wondering if I can configure one of the machines as an internal DNS server (e.g. using `dnsmasq`) which my phone should query for the  `.local` domains. This is possible, but so far what I've found about `dnsmasq` is that it allows you to set up fixed IPs as aliased to host name only.

I'm wondering -- can my linux machine get the advertised `.local` addresses and then make them a part of `dnsmasq` results?

Comment: I realise this is very late, but as of Android 12, mDNS is supported out of the box. That aside, I tinkered a bit with combining avahi-browse-domains and a python script to generate a hosts file, which dnsmasq in turn would resolve, acting as DNS server. However, I was not able to get my (pre-12) Android device to use my local DNS server, it always used google's nameservers... (as evidenced by running `dig <localhostname>.local ANY` in termux; a `.home` TLD made no difference)

Comment: ... I _think_this last issue is because Android only wants to resolve DNS queries using DNS over TLS, which can't really be done with a DNS server in the local network, having no domain name that can be externally verified.